# Does anyone know what TimezoneOffset does on LuisPredictionOptions?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I'm sending LUIS a query that is based on a time value (e.g. "what is the time 10 minutes from now" - just an example). I want the time to come back in the local timezone, so on the LuisPredictionOptions object (C#) I set the TimezoneOffset (as an example I set it to 2 hours ahead, or 120 minutes).

In Fiddler I can see when it calls the LUIS endpoint it's correctly adding "timezoneOffset=120.0".

However, the timezone comes back as UTC - it doesn't matter whether the timezoneOffset is set, or even what it is set to, the time always comes back UTC, using the builtin datetimeV2 entity.

Does anyone know what the TimezoneOffset property is for? Am I just using it incorrectly? Is there another way perhaps to get a local time from LUIS?

[Update]: Here are some examples: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/[AppId]?verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&subscription-key=[subscriptionkey]&q=/luis/v2.0/apps/c1be57f4-3850-489e-8266-db376b82c011?timezoneOffset=120&log=true

https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/[AppId]?verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&subscription-key=[subscriptionkey]&q=/luis/v2.0/apps/c1be57f4-3850-489e-8266-db376b82c011?timezoneOffset=240&log=true

and I'm trying the following example utterance: "in 10 minutes".

When I do this, the timex is in UTC (e.g. timex=2020-01-11T16:08:25) and the "value" comes back with the same value, minus the "T", as follows: value=2020-01-11 16:08:25

I could understand perhaps if the timex is in UTC, but then possibly "value" should be adjusted by the timezoneOffset?

Comment: I think you pasted the wrong value as your queries in those sample URL's

Comment: Thanks Kyle - I got this figured out though - see my comment below. I was doing some manual testing and indeed got these URLs messed up, but it was part of a wider problem figure out some time issues which I eventually came right with.

Comment: Are you going to accept Hazem's answer then?

Comment: Well, he wasn't totally correct about the url, and certainly it had nothing to do with the SDK version, so wasn't sure it was a 100% "accept". He certainly helped me find the right direction though, which is why I upvoted his answer. That make sense?

Comment: You didn't provide enough information to discover the actual problem, so given the question you asked he was as correct as he possibly could have been. But if you're not going to politely accept his answer then you should post your own answer so you can accept that.

Comment: No, the answer was indeed in the information above - the timezoneOffset is duplicated in my URLs above, -that- was the problem, that the overall URL was incorrect, it basically had a duplication of itself. That's broader than "an incorrect question mark", and I only figured it out by examining them more closely, when I realised that sections were duplicated. I also don't think it warrants necessarily another complete answer - it's not really a valid LUIS scenario, it was my own mucked up testing, partly outside of the libraries, that lead to this - hopefully no one's as silly in future :-o

Comment: You're a lot more on SO than am, so happy to go with your recommendation on this...

Comment: My recommendation is to reward the people who help you by accepting one of their answers. If the problem was your malformed URL's, both Hazem and I noticed that you had malformed URL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's an incorrect question mark in your URL, right before timezoneOffset.

Using the same query I was able to get the expected behavior, where the returned value is different by 10 minutes.

Which SDK are you using? Perhaps you're using the V3 Runtime SDK which uses the V3 endpoint that doesn't use timeZoneOffset but instead uses [datetimeReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-migration-api-v3#request-changes), and need to use the V2 Runtime SDK instead.

[https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/[app-id]?verbose=true&timezoneOffset=10&subscription-key=[key]&q=in 10 minutes](https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/[app-id]?verbose=true&timezoneOffset=10&subscription-key=[key]&q=in%2010%20minutes)

Comment: You were right, the url was totally messed up - I had two querystrings combined from some faulty testing my side. In the end, I figured out the overall solution - I was mixing up LUIS time, the user's time, and the server time where the bot was running.

Answer (score 0):

The **TimeZoneInfo** class's **FindSystemTimeZoneById** method can be used to determine the correct timezoneOffset based on system time. An example in C# is shown below:

```
// Get CST zone id
TimeZoneInfo targetZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");

// Get local machine's value of Now
DateTime utcDatetime = DateTime.UtcNow;

// Get Central Standard Time value of Now
DateTime cstDatetime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDatetime, targetZone);

// Find timezoneOffset
int timezoneOffset = (int)((cstDatetime - utcDatetime).TotalMinutes);
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-data-alteration?tabs=V2#c-code-determines-correct-value-of-timezoneoffset

Comment: This doesn't help at all, I'm afraid - I'm doing that already, and it's not sending what I expect. As an example, try the following calls: